# Is it possible to user angular 10 libraries in angular js?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-library

I am working in an angular js project, where some of the pages are made with angular 10 and used as iframes. What I am trying to achieve is, use angular 10 libraries in angular js project.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it only if you create the Angular10 project and use the libraries there (and then call to the Angular10 project with Iframe (you can communicate between the projects with Post messages).
but if you try to use angular10 in angularJS it won't work.

you can read more here:
[Post Messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)